# What's the purpose of using "algorithm = ball_tree" in sklearn.neighbors.KernelDensity?

Tags: scikit-learn, density-function, kernel-smoothing, density-estimation

In `sklearn.neighbors.KernelDensity`，there is a parameter "`algorithm = ball_tree`".  What is its specific role in KDE? Why does KDE need `ball_tree`？

see `sklearn.neighbors.KernelDensity()`:
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KernelDensity.html#sklearn.neighbors.KernelDensity

I think that using ball tree to search for neighbors will only make the algorithm slower, that's because we have to find K neighbors first (the time complexity of balltree is k*log(n) ), and then we use k neighbors for KDE . This will obviously slow down the algorithm. So why don't we give up looking for neighbors and use all the data for KDE

Comment: To find the neighbours faster.

Comment: Why does KDE need to find neighbors?  Shouldn't KDE use all the data?

Comment: No, especially for finite support kernels (eg. triangular, Epanechnikov) it makes no sense to use all data.

Comment: So, does KDE only use the data near the estimation point? How much data will be used? Can this function return the data used? Does using nearby data make KDE get density faster?

Comment: Yes, the KDE by definition is giving more weight to data near the estimation and the weight is specific to the kernel choice.

Comment: Thx，Can this function return the data used? Or, can I know how much data is used to estimate the density of a point ？

Comment: Usually we cannot but you can get the Nearest Neighbours directly. In truth, when making a KDE, we spend most of our time finding the neighbours. The calculations themselves are mostly trivial (a [WLS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighted_least_squares) in most cases)

Comment: However, the time complexity of ball tree is k*log(n),  If we use balltree to find k neighbors, the computing speed will be lower than using all data directly.

Comment: Sorry, it is unclear to me what is meant in the latest comment.

Comment: sorry I didn't make it clear, I think that using ball tree to search for neighbors will only make the algorithm slower, that's because we have to find K neighbors first (the time complexity of balltree is k*log(n) ), and then we use k neighbors for KDE .  This will obviously slow down the algorithm.  So why don't we give up looking for neighbors and use all the data for KDE.

Comment: 1. What if our kernel simply does not need all the data? 2. What if our data is too large? 3. What if our data has localised variability? 4. What if our data is multi-dimensional? Also, a brute force query would be $O(nk)$ which is even worse. We need that query because even if we use the simplest kernel possible, a rectangular one, we need to find what points are $\pm \alpha$ our query $x_q$. This subsequently requires finding  $x_q$'s NN around that ball with radius $\alpha$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112228/discussion-between-gid-and-usr11852).

Comment: Thx buddy, you've taught me a lot about KDE. But I think, for Epanechnikov, Cosine and rectangular kernel, it is necessary to search for neighbors, but if we use Gaussian kernel, neighbors should not be necessary.  However, I still can't understand 1.why it is necessary to search for neighbors when the data is too large. I think that if the data is too large, it will take more time to search for neighbors, so why don't we directly use all the data and Gaussian kernel to estimate the kernel density?

Comment: 2. Why is it necessary to search neighbors when our data is multi-dimensional? If we use multi-dimensional Gaussian kernel, we can also use all data to estimate kernel density. 3. In my algorithm, I pay great attention to the speed of the algorithm, so should I use all the data and Gaussian kernel?

Comment: 4. If the scale of each dimension of multi-dimensional data are different, how to search for neighbors? Different scale of each dimension means that it is impossible to use Euclidean distance to find neighbors.

Comment: Some remarks: (0) by not always using all the data, we can handle problems with *huge* datasets that would otherwise be computationally intractable. (1) The Gaussian kernel typically drops off so fast that for computational purposes it is truncated. (2) You have to choose scales for your coordinates intelligently, to be suitable for the problem.  After rescaling, you can use Euclidean distance.